# How can I disable EXIF support globally in LAMP stack?

Tags: php, lamp, exif

I cannot seem to disable the EXIF support which is enabled by default when doing a traditional LAMP stack install.

I cannot come up with anything better than to comment out EXIF in the php.ini file.

```
;[exif]
; Exif UNICODE user comments are handled as UCS-2BE/UCS-2LE and JIS as JIS.
; With mbstring support this will automatically be converted into the encoding
; given by corresponding encode setting. When empty mbstring.internal_encoding
; is used. For the decode settings you can distinguish between motorola and
; intel byte order. A decode setting cannot be empty.
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/exif.configuration.php#ini.exif.encode-unicode
;exif.encode_unicode = ISO-8859-15
```

Although after commenting out the `[exif]` line of code and saving php.ini, stopping the server, and then starting the server again I still  receive phpinfo() function information which states that EXIF is indeed still enabled. (See image below)

[image]

Comment: It's a compiled-in module. You can't disable it entirely. (`disable_functions` is a clumsy workaround though.)

Comment: In case of WAMP with PHP 5.5.12 I find `extension=php_exif.dll` in php.ini. If it's in fact precompiled in PHP for LAMP I guess you need to get one compiled without exif.

Comment: I will look for a PHP LAMP install without the packaged, compiled EXIF module. Thanks for leading me in the correct direction.